# Is any operator from $l_{p}$ to a quotient of $l_{r}$($1\leq r<p<\infty$) compact?

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $1\leq r<p<\infty$. Let $T$ be an operator from  $l_{p}$ to a quotient of $l_{r}$. Is $T$ compact?

Comment: Since each separable Banach space is a quotient of $l_1$, there is a non-compact operator (actually an isomorphism) from $l_p$ to a quotient space of $l_1$, isomorphic to $l_p$.

Comment: Thanks, Taras. If $r$ is the conjugate of $p$($\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{r}=1, p>2)$, is the question true?

Comment: Yes, for $1<r<p<\infty$. Because, for example, $T^*$ is an operator from a subspace of $\ell_{r^*}$ into $\ell_{p^*}$, hence is compact by (the proof of) Pitt's theorem.

Comment: Thanks,Bill. The proof of Pitt's theorem appears in  Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's classical book.